# Chrome extension message between users

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, p2p, chrome-gcm

Is it possible to send messages between users directly without a server in Chrome extensions (P2P)?

Or does it require a server (NodeJS, for example)?

Maybe use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client), I do not understand the logic and work ([official example extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gcm-notifications/gpededflkpcoehfjpdecdkoiagajloin)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Chrome does not give any tools to do so; any kind of interaction has to go through a 3rd-party server.

GCM, for that matter, is just a routing service between clients and an app server.

Extensions cannot listen for incoming connections. Chrome Apps, however, do. In that case, you can build a P2P application.

Comment: Perhaps do without a server directly between two users (P2P) of the Chrome App? [chrome.socket](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by the last phrase.

Comment: thou i havent played with it, if users have google accounts you might get something from the drive realtime api https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/